A Collatz-like map?
Consider the map $\psi$ acting on triples $(a\leq b\leq c)$ of three positive natural integers with $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b,c)=1$ as follows:
Set $$(a',b',c')=\left(\frac{a}{\mathrm{gcd}(a,bc)},\frac{b}{\mathrm{gcd}(b,ac)},\frac{c}{\mathrm{gcd}(c,ab)}\right).$$
Reorder the triplet $(a',b',c')$ in increasing order $(r=\min(a',b',c'),s,t=\max(a',b',c'))$
and set
$$\psi((a,b,c))=(r+s,r+t,r+s+t)\ .$$
We consider the associated dynamical system obtained by iterating $\psi$.
Thousands of runs with either small initial values or random initial values all
ended up in five cycles:
Four cycles of length two given by
$(2,3,4),(3,4,6)$
$(2,8,9),(5,10,14)$
$(5,9,12),(7,8,12)$
$(21,22,38),(30,32,51)$
and a cycle of length $17$ containing $(3,18,20)$.
I guess there are other orbits but they are rather hard to find.
I would be interested in additional finite orbits and candidates for
infinite orbits.
(I will update according to new results. I will accept an answer showing
the existence of only finitely many periodic orbits, of infinitely many periodic orbits
or of an unbounded orbit.)
Additional cycles :
Length 3:
(15,217,228),(81,222,298),(64,176,213) (communicated by Peter Muller)
Length 6 : $(3790,5014,7317),\ldots$ (Peter Muller)
Length 12 : $(1039,4442,5388),\ldots$ (Peter Muller)
Added The three maps obtained by considering
$$(r,s,t)\longmapsto (r,r+s,r+s+t),$$
$$(r,s,t)\longmapsto (s,r+s,r+s+t),$$
$$(r,s,t)\longmapsto (\min(r+s,t)),\max(r+s,t),r+s+t)$$
at the final step behave similarly.
One gets probably more similar maps by
considering signs (or more generally integral coefficients not necessarily in $\{0,1\}$)
or higher dimensions after taking care of
the first stage (given a prime dividing
several coefficients, divide them all by this prime. This can be done without factorisation using only greatest common divisors).
These maps have a contracting component coming from arithmethics, a permutational stage and an expanding component coming from linear algebra. Assuming (very naively and probably incorrectly) independence of these components
one can compute in a naive way (using suitable random hypotheses and perhaps neglecting the permutational stage) the contracting and the expanding contributions and compare them. This should give an indication on expected behaviours.

Divide then $x,y$ by $\gcd(x,y)$ for all pairs $x,y$ occuring
in $(a,b,c)$ — to me at least, it wasn’t clear that this does not depend on the order in which you perform the divisions. But it is: the result is just $(a/{\gcd}(a,bc),b/{\gcd}(b,ac),c/{\gcd}(c,ab))$.

(Sorry, I seem to have conflated two different versions of that sentence. It should read “it does not” rather than “it is”.)

You are of course right. However, algorithmically, my formulation is faster for large arguments.

Cycle of length $3$ through $(64, 176, 213)$.

Thanks, added .

This question is only very marginally Collatz like. I suspect that the negative reception is in part due to the title.

@JoshuaZ : I think downvoting becomes at some stage self-inforcing. Perhaps it's the title, or the question, probably nothing to do.

I think the similarity is that in the Collatz iteration you divide by two until something is odd and here you divide until the elements have gcd 1.

We can just confine attention to triples with $\gcd(a,b,c)=1.$ I think that the multistage iteration is better understood as follows: Let  $u=\gcd(a,b),$ $v=\gcd(a,c)$ and $w=\gcd(b,c)$ then $u,v,w$ are pairwise relatively prime and $a=uva'$, $b=uwb'$, and $c=vwc'$ with $a',b',c'$ pairwise relatively prime. Then the triple $(a',b',c') =(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,c)}\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)\gcd(b,c)}\frac{c}{\gcd(a,c)\gcd(b,c)}     )$ is sorted giving $(p,q,r)$ from which $(p+q,q+r,p+q+r)$ is returned.
Q: What is the motivation for this rather than say, $(p+r,q+r,p+q+r)$? It seems unsymmetric.

@AaronMeyerowitz: Thanks. Your proposition is much clearer and I have rewritten the post accordingly.

You rewrote it according to the formulation of @EmilJeřábek. Which is also fine. Mine has three relatively small $\gcd$ operations.

@AaronMeyerowitz: The other formulations give seemingly rise to exploding orbits: One has to use the smallest element three times.
(There are however also variations with signs: One choses signs in order to get an invertible linear map (over $\mathbb Z$). Some sign-choices are interesting (my example is seemingly the only case involving only additions.))

Some statistics on the cycles {smallest element; length; frequency}:
${(2,3,4);2;0.452}$,
${(5,9,12):2:0.333}$,
${(3,18,20):17:0.188}$,
${(2,8,9):2:0.0258}$,
${(21,22,38):2:0.00066}$,
${(15,217,228):3:0.00003}$.
Note that the last cycle is quite rare.
I did $10^6$ runs with uniform random integers $\leq 10^4$. I did not use the condition $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$.

Ac cycle of length $6$ through $(3790, 5014, 7317)$ and of length $12$ through $(1039, 4442, 5388)$.

@PeterMueller Thanks. What's your secret weapon for finding these solutions?

To clarify my first comment: I’m not suggesting that my expression is easier to compute, or better in any way. The only point is that it is symmetric, proving that the result of the operation does not depend on the order in which you perform the three pairwise divisions by gcd: without this knowledge, the original formulation was not even well defined, as it didn’t specify the order. Concerning the later edits, $(r,s,t)\mapsto(r,r+s,r+s+t)$ definitely looks more natural than $(r+s,r+t,r+s+t)$.

@RolandBacher There is nothing special about my straightforward Python code. It runs a little faster (about a factor 2) with the JIT compiler pypy3 and the AOT compiler codon (about a factor 3). It has now finished all start tuples $a,b,c$ with $a\le b\le c\le4000$ (and $a,b,c$ w.l.o.g. pairwise prime). A thing to note: I really check for each start whether it eventually becomes periodic. One could save computations if one stores tuples which are known to finish in known cycles. But this set would explode in size, so I doubt that it gives a performance improvement.

If there is interest, I'm glad to share the code in an answer (which wouldn't be an answer though ...).

@PeterMueller Thank you very much. I did computations in Maple (which is of course fairly slow). Perhaps I will update my C-programming skills a bit.

for a modest speed up, only consider trajectories as long as they  stay above (or equal to) the initial triple in "size" which could be the maximum element. For example the initial triple $(2,17,1025)$ hits $(113,139,228)$ after $6$ steps, Since $228<1025$, we terminate.
If we kept going we would hit

$(36,139,158)$ at step $161$
$(54,70,101)$ at step $165$
$(9,22,30)$ at step  $174$
$(8,14,19)$ at step $175$
$(4,11,14)$ at step $214$

That last triple is in the $17$-cycle. Presumably we discovered that $17$-cycle with initial triple $(4,11,14)$.

Thanks Aaron, another trick is to start with the linear map $\psi$, followed by 'arithmetic reduction' (division by gcd's). This leads to periodic orbits with smaller coeffs which are therefore slightly easier to find.
